# Nginx -> Unicorn - Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: ruby, nginx, sinatra, unicorn

We have Sinatra application in production.

The application has back-end & front-end part.
Back-end & frond-end are tightly coupled and represent monolith.
The back-end of Sinatra app is mostly simple proxy to "real" back-end written on Java/Sping/Mongo. The "real" back-end is accessible via set of rests.

So the full path a request that goes from end user to back-end is as follows:
UI -> Nginx -> Unicorn -> Sinatra -> Java/Spring back-end -> Sinatra -> Unicorn -> Nginx -> UI.

Recently we introduced the feature that allows user every 5 sec to receive messages from server while browser is open. The feature is implemented via

```
    setInterval(function() {
        if (self.tab_visibility() == 'visible') {
            if (!self.osdDisplayed) {
                self.getOsdMessage();
            }
        }
    }, 5000);
```

The approach is quite stupid and should be rewritten in favor of push notifications from server to front-end. But currently it works via setInterval.

So the issue we started to bump into was that Nginx was not able to get open socket connection to Unicorn.

In Nginx log file there was an error:

> unix:/tmp/unicorn.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
>   while connecting to upstream

End-user wasn't able to open the site - error 503!
But at the same time in Unicorn log I saw a lot of successfully completed requests with 200 response code.

**Question**: why wan't I able to open the site while other users according to Unicorn log were processed successfully?

**Nginx.conf**:

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    index   index.html index.htm;

    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  localhost;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
}
```

**/etc/nginx/conf.d/web_client.conf**

```
log_format compression  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                        '"$request" $status $bytes_sent '
                        '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" "$gzip_ratio"';

limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=conn_limit_per_ip:10m;
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=req_limit_per_ip:10m rate=1000r/s;

limit_conn_status 405;
limit_req_status 405;

upstream v-web {
  server unix:/tmp/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen       8008;
  set_real_ip_from  10.0.0.0/8;
  real_ip_header    X-Forwarded-For;
  real_ip_recursive on;
  root /opt/v/Web-Client-http_auth/public;
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/nginx.access.log compression buffer=32k;
  error_log  /var/log/nginx/nginx.error.log warn;

  limit_conn conn_limit_per_ip 10;
  limit_req zone=req_limit_per_ip burst=1200 nodelay;

  keepalive_timeout  75;
  sendfile        on;
  tcp_nopush     on;
  open_file_cache           max=1000 inactive=20s;
  open_file_cache_valid     30s;
  open_file_cache_min_uses  2;
  open_file_cache_errors    on;
  gzip              on;
  gzip_http_version 1.0;
  gzip_disable      "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";
  gzip_buffers 4 16k;
  gzip_comp_level 2;
  gzip_min_length 0;
  gzip_types text/plain text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
  gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;

  location / {
    try_files $uri @v-web;
    index  index.html index.htm;
  }

  location @v-web {
    proxy_pass http://v-web;
    proxy_redirect     off;
    proxy_set_header   Host             $http_host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    client_max_body_size       10m;
    client_body_buffer_size    128k;

    proxy_connect_timeout      60;
    proxy_send_timeout         60;
    proxy_read_timeout         60;

    proxy_buffer_size          16k;
    proxy_buffers              8 64k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size    128k;
    proxy_temp_file_write_size 128k;
  }

  error_page  404              /404.html;
  location = /404.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }
  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
  location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }
  error_page   405 /custom.html;
  location = /custom.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }


  location /nginx_status {
       stub_status on;
       access_log   off;
       allow 127.0.0.1;
       deny all;
  }
}
```

The interaction of Sinatra app with Java "real" back-end is handle via following code snippets:

**connection_pool.rb**

```
######################################################################
# ConnectionPool
######################################################################
class ConnectionPool
  include Singleton

  ######################################################################
  def initialize
    @mutex = Mutex.new
    @condition = ConditionVariable.new

    @connections = []
    @limit = settings.api_pool_limit
  end

  ######################################################################
  def new_connection
    handle = HTTPClient.new
    handle.follow_redirect_count = settings.api_redirect_limit
    handle.connect_timeout = settings.api_timeout
    handle.send_timeout = settings.api_timeout
    handle.receive_timeout = settings.api_timeout
    handle.ssl_config.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
    {
      :handle => handle,
      :locked => false
    }
  end

  ######################################################################
  def get_connection
    @mutex.synchronize do
      connection = get_connection_from_pool
      return connection if connection

      if @connections.length < @limit
        connection = new_connection
        connection[:locked] = true

        @connections.push(connection)

        return connection
      end

      loop do
        @condition.wait(@mutex)

        connection = get_connection_from_pool
        return connection if connection
      end
    end
  end

  ######################################################################
  def get_connection_from_pool
    @connections.each do |connection|
      next if connection[:locked]

      connection[:locked] = true
      return connection
    end
    return nil
  end


  ######################################################################
  def start
    return unless block_given?

    connection = get_connection
    begin
      yield connection[:handle]
    ensure
      @mutex.synchronize do
        connection[:locked] = false
        @condition.signal
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**connection.rb**

```
######################################################################
# Connection
######################################################################
class Connection
  include ::CustomLogger
  include ::Sinatra::Helpers
  attr_reader :session

  ######################################################################
  def initialize(request, session)
    @session = SessionStore.new(session)
    @session.read_credentials_from_cookies(request)
    @cookieManager = WebAgent::CookieManager.new
  rescue Dalli::RingError, Timeout::Error => e
    log_error("Connection initialize: memcache is unreachable #{e.message} \n")
  end

  ######################################################################
  def send(type, relative_url, options = {}, cache)
    locale_for_cache = begin
      options[:headers]["x-vidmind-locale"]
    rescue
      ''
    end
    url = "#{settings.wildfire_base_url}#{relative_url}"
    result = nil
    if cache and !development?
      result = get_from_cache(relative_url, locale_for_cache)
      return result unless result.blank?
    end
    ConnectionPool.instance.start do |http|
      if @session.api_cookie

        cookie = find_session_cookie(@cookieManager.cookies)
        unless cookie
          cookie = WebAgent::Cookie.new
          cookie.name = 'JSESSIONID'
          cookie.url = URI.parse(settings.wildfire_base_url)
          cookie.domain = cookie.url.host
          cookie.path = cookie.url.path
        end
        cookie.value = @session.api_cookie

        @cookieManager.cookies = []
        @cookieManager.add(cookie)
        http.cookie_manager = @cookieManager
        request_cookies = http.cookies.map{ |i| {i.name => i.value} }
      else
        http.cookie_manager = WebAgent::CookieManager.new
        request_cookies = [{ 'JSESSIONID' => '' }]
      end

      headers = {}
      headers.merge!(options[:headers]) if options[:headers]
      headers.merge!({ 'Content-Type' => options[:data_type] }) if options[:data_type]
      headers['X-Forwarded-For'] = settings.forwarded_for if settings.forwarded_for

      time_start = Time.now
      response = http.request(type, url, {
        :query => options[:query],
        :body => options[:data],
        :header => headers,
        :follow_redirect => false
      })
      # httpclient doesn't know Post/Redirect/Get pattern
      if invalid_http_status?(response.status)
        url = response.header['location'][0]

        response = http.request(:get, url, {
          :header => options[:headers],
          :follow_redirect => true
        })
      end

      time_end = Time.now
      json = process_response(response.content)

      log({
        request_cookies: request_cookies,
        response_cookies: http.cookies.map{ |i| {i.name => i.value}},
        time_start: time_start,
        time_end: time_end,
        url: relative_url,
        type: type,
        status: response.status,
        body: json,
        options: options,
        rk: response.content,
        encoding: response.body_encoding,
        fingerprint: headers['x-vidmind-device-id']
      })

      result = {
        success: response_success?(response.status, json),
        code: response.status,
        json: json
      }
      cookie = find_session_cookie(http.cookies)
      @session.api_cookie = cookie.value if cookie
      count_api_requests(time_end, time_start)
    end
    if cache and result[:success] and !development?
      unless result.blank?
        set_cache(relative_url, locale_for_cache, result)
      end
    end
    result
    rescue Exception => e
      log_error " raised for url: #{relative_url} #{e} "
      log_error   " \r\nrequest_cookies #{@session.api_cookie} \r\n"
      raise e if e.is_a?(WildfireError)
  end

  ######################################################################
  def find_session_cookie(cookies)
    cookies.each do |cookie|
      return cookie if 'JSESSIONID'.casecmp(cookie.name) == 0
    end if cookies
    nil
  end

  ######################################################################
  protected

    def process_response(response)
      begin
        response.empty? ? {} : JSON.parse(response)
      rescue
        {'error' => response}
      end
    end

    def response_error?(json)
      res = (json.kind_of?(Hash) && json.has_key?('error')) ||
      (json.kind_of?(Array) && json.first && json.first.has_key?('error')) || json.kind_of?(String)
      res
    end

    def response_success?(status, json)
      !(status < 200 or status >= 300) && !response_error?(json)
    end

    def invalid_http_status?(status)
      if status == 503
        raise WildfireConnectionError
      elsif status == 403
        raise WFSessionExpirationException
      end
      status >= 300 and status < 400
    end
end
```

Comment: Inside the main nginx config, `Nginx.conf`, there's a `location /` block that's empty. Is that expected?

Comment: Could you try changing unicorn to use the a normal tcp connection instead of a unix domain socket and test?  Also what about ulimits and file descriptors for your instance?